# with NodeJS, What's the best way to parse a file upload that does not necessarily end?

Tags: http, rest, file-upload, node.js, keep-alive

Short summary: How to accept content that may be endless and not uploaded at once (the connection needs to be kept alive), in a scenario where I'm the server and I'd like the clients to make those uploads in a RESTful (or something close) way ?

In the same way that I can make an http server that keeps the connection alive with a client and may continue sending content that the client reads and parses intantly (probably using a browser), I need to keep a connection opened with a client that will send me data that may not end or be continuously uploaded.

One (simple) way to do this would be simply to have a TCP server and then clients would write data to a socket.

But how do I do this with an HTTP PUT request ? [This](http://debuggable.com/posts/streaming-file-uploads-with-node-js:4ac094b2-b6c8-4a7f-bd07-28accbdd56cb) answers half of the question: "How will I parse a file upload continuously, without the upload finishing ?" But how will clients proceed to upload something that is not even a file and are separate blocks of data, like if they would be writing those blocks of data to a socket ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data isn't going to have a discrete end, then you're not really performing an upload; you're doing a streaming scenario.  For a streaming scenario, socket handling is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

First I think Sonier is right. But I found this solution by [Felix called "Streaming file uploads with node.js"](http://debuggable.com/posts/streaming-file-uploads-with-node-js:4ac094b2-b6c8-4a7f-bd07-28accbdd56cb) which might be useful.

Furthermore I think node.js might not be best fit for this, because everything has to be kept in memory and with big file-size you can hit a very hard wall. Some other popular node.js file upload solutions are:

- https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable
- https://github.com/rootslab/formaline
- https://github.com/FooBarWidget/multipart-parser